# prev() in "on" method in jquery

Tags: jquery, syntax, selector

So I have this:

```
$(".change_cont").prev().click(function(e){
  alert("Hello World");
}
```

I would like for this to work on newly created elements, like this:

```
$("body").on("click", $(".change_cont").prev(), function(){
  alert("Hello World");
}
```

This doesn't work. is there a right syntax for this or is this just impossible?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML, and point out which elements you're trying to target exactly? Technically in normal selectors, you can't go *back*, but you can go *forward*. So we might be able to help in some sort of `#parent > .first-level .child + .target` kind of way

Comment: To tell you the truth, I've always wanted to use it with the actual element, instead of the string!  This always seemed a bit backwards to me!  Maybe one day this will be possible.

Comment: @SolomonClosson if you're talking about delegated syntax, how can you use it with an actual element that _doesn't exist yet_?

Comment: Ohh, yeah, true, but if it does exist, like right after it gets created.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the following?

```
var myElementId = "#" + $(".change_cont").prev().attr("id");

$("body").on("click", myElementId, function(){
  alert("Hello World");
});
```

This would require that element to have an id though.  If it doesn't you can use the class instead I suppose, if it has a class assigned to it.  If nothing is assigned to that element, than just assign it an id or a class than.

If there is no identifying class or id on the previous element, than why not create it when the element gets created?  In that case, you would just add a class to them, and than use the class name instead of the id attribute:

```
$(".change_cont").each(function(e){
    if (!$(this).prev().hasClass('myClass'))
        $(this).prev().addClass('myClass');
});

$("body").on("click", ".myClass", function(){
  alert("Hello World");
});
```

Comment: I think the OP means the previous element will be dynamic, and not have a specific class or ID or any identifying features other than it's the previous sibling of `.change_cont`

Comment: Surely you mean `$("body").on("click", '#'+myElementId, function(){`

Comment: Thanks for trying, but if I give the element an Id it would be a lot easier with no need for the function.

Comment: Updated with giving the element a `class` instead of an `id` attribute, which will work.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery api http://api.jquery.com/on/ said that the second argument `selector` should have type **"String"**, in your case it's jQuery object, so I think your binding will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic elements will only be added by your code, so each time that happens, just tag the elements of interest with a class:

```
function updateElements() {
    $('.change_cont').prev().addClass('contClick');
}
```

and then use that class in your delegated handler:

```
$('body').on('click', '.contClick', function() {
     ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible to select the next element using `prev + sibling` selector. Check if you could select the next element of another element and achieve the same result.

```
$("body").on("click", ".change_cont_another + *", function(){
  alert("Hello World");
}
```